# Using HTML.DisplayFor in Partial View

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I moved the list of Resources from my Resource Index View to a partial view _ResourceInList.

The original view for Resources looked like this

```
....<dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RatePerHour)
    </dd>
```

Moving this to the partial view I had to strip out the @HTML.DisplayFor() lines and use bare @Model to reference the data.

```c
@model Proj.Models.Resource
<tr>
    <td>
        @Model.Name
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Team.Name
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.EmploymentStatus.Status
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.RatePerHour
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.MaxAvailability
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Note
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ResourceID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = Model.ResourceID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.ResourceID })
    </td>
</tr>
```

However I decorated my models for a reason but when I try to use the following variations it complains

```
<td> 
    @Html.DisplayFor(@Model.RatePerHour)
</td>
```

> Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

```
<td> 
         @Html.DisplayFor(@Model => model.RatePerHour)
</td>
```

Comment: You first snippet is `DisplayNameFor()` but then you talk about `.DisplayFor()` - which is it? (they are 2 different things)

Comment: Should be         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RatePerHour)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the value you need to use it as this

```
<td> 
         @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.RatePerHour)
</td>
```

and if you want to show the Label

```
<td> 
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RatePerHour)
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why its working now but the solutions wsa

```
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RatePerHour)
</td>
```

I'm fairly confident this was the first thing I tried.